# Set y get valores en blanco

Tags: c#

Estoy creando una librería para desde ahí recoger valores y enviarlos al datagrid de un form, utilizando set y get, pero al momento de insertar los datos  estos aparecen en blanco.

```
public string EstablecerDomicilio
        {
            get
            {
                return dom2;
            }
            set
            {
                dom2 = value;
            }

        }
```

Comment: "*al momento de insertar los datos estos aparecen en blanco*". Nos iría muy bien que mostraras cómo insertas los datos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como dice paper, al momento de insertar los datos donde? Este codigo que representa? que hace tu sistema?

Comment: al insertar los datos en donde ? porque si trabajas con objeto no existe ese concepto de insertar. Como creas la instancia de la clase que tiene esa propiedad ?

Comment: dom2 donde esta definido, como llamas al setter y getter ???